# Render JavaScript in XSL

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I need a div to have the following Javascript associated with it:

`onclick="resize('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4')"`

In my XSL, `var1, var2, var3, var4` hold strings`Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4` for current node. So, using `xsl:attribute name='onclick'`, I would like to associate the JS with the div. The problem I am facing is because of escaping single quotes in XSL to render it in output page (that is what I think).

Any idea how to go about it?

EDIT:
My XSL code to get the javascript onclick function call string is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('resize(', '&apos;', $var1, '&apos;', ',', '&apos;', $var2, '&apos;', ',', '&apos;', $var3, '&apos;', ',', '&apos;', $var4, '&apos;', ')'"/>
```

And IE6 [Yes its IE6, my machine has XP with IE6 :( ] shows the error:

```
Expression expected. concat('resize(', ''', $var1, ''', ',', ''', $var2, ''', ',', ''', $var3...
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant part of your XSLT file and the output you are currently getting? This would greatly help in solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny enough there seems to be no real good escape sequence for single quotes inside attribute values. You should be able to go with:

```
    <xsl:attribute name="onClick">resize('<xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>','<xsl:value-of select="$var2"/>','<xsl:value-of select="$var3"/>', '<xsl:value-of select="$var4"/>')</xsl:attribute>
```

At least IntelliJ likes this. It is a bit long-winded but should be safe to use even with older XSLT processors like IE6. I have no IE6 here to check it, though. Btw. IE6 is somewhat outdated technology, so you should really get rid of it.

Comment: It worked. :) And regarding IE, this machine of mine has IE6. I use latest Firefox. Was just testing it on IE6. Thanks man.